# Can't receive msmq messages

Tags: windows-xp, msmq

I have a problem with an app that uses msmq: on a specific machine this app can send msmq messages but does not seem to receive any messages.

This is happening only on a specific machine (using XP).

How can I debug the problem? Where can I find clues as to where the problem is occuring and why?

On the remote machine the messages are stuck in the outgoing queue.

This machine used to be able to receive messages and one day it stopped working. It was not obvious what happened on the machine that could be correlated to the loss of the ability to receive messages.

I have checked that port 1801 is open.

(I didn't find anything in the event viewer)

Comment: Has the 'bad receiver' machine been restarted (whole machine or messaging service)? **Has it ever successfully received messages?** How many other machines are connecting to this machine's queues? How many queues on this machine? You should edit your question to include a bullet list of the remedies you've tried already. What security scheme is being applied to the queue? Private or public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "receive" messages, do you mean you are unable to remove messages from a queue, or that no messages can be delivered to the machine?

Most common cause is permissions - easiest test for that is to set Full Control for Everyone and Anonymous Logon.

=== 4th Feb ====

If the messages are stuck in the outgoing queue then the state of the queue is important.
If it is "*connected*" then the problem is with getting the messages to be accepted by the destination queue manager.
If it is instead "*waiting to connect*" or similar then there is a problem instead at the network connection level.

As the messages are waiting to be delivered, there is no error state so no logging will help here. MSMQ expects messages to be delayed so nothing is going wrong here as it is assumed the blockage will clear at some point in the future. Eventually the messages will time out and be discarded unless you are using Negative Source Journaling.

=== 8th Feb ====

OK, if "DIRECT=TCP:1.2.3.4\Private$\MyQueue" works but "DIRECT=OS:servername\Private$\MyQueue" doesn't then it looks like a name resolution issue. 
Check the sending machine for the IP address of the DNS server it is using for name resolution; check this server for entries for the destination machine name. On the sending machine check the HOSTS and LMHOSTS files for any entries for the destination machine name. You could even try adding an entry to HOSTS that maps destination machine name to IP address.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: as I said the messages are stuck in the outgoing queue on the remote machine (so the messages are not delivered to the problematic machine)

Comment: I assume you mean the state of the outgoing queue. How do I find out the state of that queue (if possible not programmaticcally)? Thanks. Changing the permissions as you suggested didn't solve the problem (so I guess this points to a network problem).

Comment: In Computer Management, State is the 5th column along when viewing Outgoing Queues. Next hop is useful too for checking you are using the right IP address.

Comment: So the state is "waiting to connect" and there is nothing in "next hop(s)"

Comment: What you will probably see is a period of "waiting to connect" (which lasts for the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\WaitTime setting) followed by an attempt to connect followed by a period of "waiting to connect" again, in a loop. You should be seeing an IP address of the destination in the Next Hop column, though. One test for name resolution issues is to address the message using the IP address instead.

Comment: It does work with the IP address instead of the machine name. I've tried restarting msmq service on both machines but no luck. I've tried various registry settings but no luck...Also tried ipconfig /flushdns (still not working). TCPView shows for mqsvc.exe local address (0.0.0.0:1801) remote address (0.0.0.0) State (LISTENING)

Answer (score 1):

Receiver is listening on 1801, but can sender connect to that port? On the sender, go to command line and execute: telnet receiverHostName 1801
That will check if connection can be opened to that port. Maybe firewall or other software blocking traffic?

Comment: +1. This was the issue for me in the end. It's such a basic thing that I guess many overlook mentioning it in their articles/tutorials. I opened port 1801 (the port MSMQ listens to incoming traffic for) on my service host and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

To debug message queueing issues:

- Use an application to inspect the machine and queues. Suggest writing your own, or something like [QueueExplorer demo](http://www.cogin.com/mq/). This is the quickest way to determine what the nature of the  problem is: endpoint permissions/security, networking, malformed message, etc.
- implement logging at the sender's end. Perhaps there's an error message being returned by the bad receiver, or perhaps the sender can't establish a connection, or maybe the message is too large.

Answer (score 0):

I usually run the app under Network-Service and give full permission set for this user for Queues. If I have Desktop endpoint try connect to messaging with Network-Service user.

Try it might work.

Comment: Wait, you grant *an entire service account, not just used by your application but many* full permissions to things?

Comment: Msmq first of all is a transport protocol. If you want n computers to use it to exchange messages you start msmq on all machines with the same user from your AD or as Network Service by default. Stating this assures that if a message is queued it will reach destination host. The second part it you give to your application user appropriate permissions to Send/Receive message from queues. Another option will be to connect to the queue under a user which has Send/Receive permission set.